# What type of media server software do I need to transcode in near real time?

Tags: video

Can anyone help me find a software stack for doing near real time video encoding/transcoding?

I want to allow users to upload videos(wmv, avi, mov, flash video, other formats) to my website. As soon as the file is uploaded, I want to encode/transcode it into h.264 (preferably with an API so I can get progress percentage etc) so that I can then play it back via html5 or a flash player.

Anyone have any guidance for me on this?

Oh, and the server platform can be either windows or linux.

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG is what you're looking for.  You can use it to transcode most anything, it can easily be integrated via STDIO, and there are a handful of library versions of it you can use as well.

I'd recommend hopping over to [StackOverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com), where this topic has been heavily discussed.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that mplayer and vlc are where you want to start lookIng.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding.com offers cloud-based high-speed conversion. Their standard plans aren't instant (up to 30 minute queue time), but they do offer encode-as-you-upload (meaning that they start encoding during the upload process, which is awesome).

You'll need to contact them for more info and pricing on that.

Be aware: What you're wanting to do is both complex and expensive unless you hire someone, in which case it's just expensive (assuming your website becomes anywhere near popular).

Answer (score 0):

You could look into MediaTomb it runs on linux. I use it for real time transcoding to my direcTv box and PS3